# Auto Layout questions for UILabel sizing (project attached)

Tags: ios, uilabel, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I'm a bit stumped regarding a few things I am trying to setup using Auto Layout.

Here's what I currently have. As you can see, I am trying to implement something similar to the Messages.app. I made the test/demo project very similar to explain it a bit easier.

Here's the project: https://github.com/runmad/MessagingApp

[image]

I am trying to achieve a few things:

**• Use Auto Layout for self-sizing cells:**
I have set this up no problem, since it pretty much comes for free.

**• Add inset between the label's frame and its text:** I was under this was possible using `layoutMargins` (http://carpeaqua.com/2014/07/24/auto-layout-in-ios-8-layout-margins/) but I have no been able to do this.

**• Size the label to the text OR a 60% maximum width of the `contentView`**: I have been able to do this for the grey messages above (except maybe not for the first grey one?), but I have not been able to correct size the blue ("sent") messages to be a maximum of 60% of the width of the cell's `contentView`.

I am targeting iOS 8.0, so for `layoutMargins`, this should be OK. I am also using Storyboard and Auto Layout within IB.

Any help and insight much appreciated!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want the text to only go 60% of the way to the right edge of the label? Do you want it to start at the left edge, or inset from both edges?

Comment: I want the label to be the size of the text OR a maximum of 60% of the width if the text is too long, starting from either side, depending on if it's sent or received message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your constraints (for the blue label) is that you can't use a multiplier with a leading (or left or top) constraint. The value of leading or top is 0, so multiplying that by something doesn't get you anywhere. You need to make the constraint between the trailing edge of the cell (like you do for the gray label), and the leading edge of the label. Since you're measuring from the other side, you want that to have a multiplier of 0.4 rather than 0.6.

[image]